# Subscript out of bounds error in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

While executing the below code using rmarkdown

````
```{r}
rasList <- list.files("NDVI_Modis/AOI_NDVI", full.names = TRUE, pattern = ".tif$")
NDVI_Otjo_stack <- stack(rasList)
```
````

I get the error

```
Quitting from lines 42-44 (MODIS_TimeSeriesProcessor.Rmd) 
Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... stack -> stack -> .local -> stack -> stack -> .local
Execution halted
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's `stack(rasList)` supposed to do?

Comment: Hi jmutua, this appears to be an R error, unrelated to the use of RMarkdown. What is the goal for the snippet of code?

Comment: @lukeA in 'stack(rasList)', _rasList_ is a list to be stacked using the **stack** function.

Comment: @Keith Hughitt I want to stack all the rasters in the list

Comment: But `list.files` returns a vector with paths and file names or with length 0, if no file name matches the pattern. `stack`, however, _"Stack[s] Vectors from a Data Frame or List"_ (`?stack`), which - to me - does not make any sense here.

Comment: I think you are perhaps skipping a step to read the files in? Check out the `readTIFF()` function from the `tiff` package. Also, if you are attempt to take _n_ m by p images and create one (n x n) by p matrix, see the `rbind` function.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, the code works well in R but when executed in rmarkdown I get the error.